# Alexa home skill request not reaching lambda function after a while

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smart-home-skill

We have an Alexa home skill developed and is under testing. For the Home devices control

**ENVIRONMENT DETAILS:**

Alexa Home skill

Lambda functions for the execution

Account linking has been enabled

Once I enable the skill, the skill is getting enabled successfully. Starting discovery of devices and finding the devices. Post that I was able to control the devices as well

But say after an hour. When I come back to the app or the echo devices. If I start controlling the device. it displays server is unresponsive and says something went wrong. Try disabling and enabling your skill. If I do that it works fine for an hour. Again it goes to unresponsiveness.

Did anyone experienced such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same symptoms and the root cause was because we weren't properly providing a refresh token, and our access token had a 1 hour TTL.

From the [Alexa Account Linking Debugging Tips](https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/articles/38610/alexa-debugging-account-linking.html) page:

> Problem: Account linking succeeds, but after some time the customer has to link accounts again
> Solution: This usually indicates that Alexa was unable to use the provided refresh token to grab a new access/refresh token pair.
>
> 1. Ensure that the access token time to live (TTL) is more than 5 minutes.
> 2. Ensure that your authorization server can successfully refresh the access/refresh token pair when presented with a refresh token by
>    Alexa.
> 3. Ensure that you are not invalidating refresh tokens too early - Alexa may take some time after the access token has expired to refresh
>    the token, and if your authorization server has already invalidated
>    the refresh token, Alexa will not be able to refresh the
>    access/refresh token pair and your customer will have their account
>    linking disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Does your skill implement [EnpointHealth](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-endpointhealth.html)?

If not, it may affect the connectivity status in the app.

Comment: I had the exact same problem that this question describes and tried implementing EndpointHeath for my Alexa Smart Home skill, however that didn't help in my case.

Comment: Make sure that you include EndpointHealth in the discovery AND that you include it in the StateReports when ReportState directives are received.

Comment: Yeah, our Discovery and StateReports include device health (connectivity and radio diagnostics). Right now we're pursuing the possibility that the oauth bearer token isn't being properly/successfully refreshed, since those tokens were set to be valid for 1 hour - which is the same time cadence of the skill breaking.